# How to tell if a list inside a dict is empty

Tags: python

I have a `movietimes={}`

It a dict I make by this code:

```
for i in Showtime.objects.filter(movie_id=movieid,theater_id=theaterid,datetime__range=(today,tomorrow))):
    if i.mvtype not in movietimes:
        movietimes[i.mvtype] = []
    if not i.movietime > today :
        movietimes[i.mvtype].append(i.movietime.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))

if not movietimes : #this have bug
    for i in Showtime.objects.filter(movie_id=movieid,datetime__range=(yesterday,today)):
        if i.mvtype not in movietimes:
            movietimes[i.mvtype] = []
        movietimes[i.mvtype].append(i.movietime.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))
return movietimes
```

result like this:

```
     "Times": {
                "ONE: [
                    "2014-12-24T10:40:00.000000Z", 
                    "2014-12-24T12:45:00.000000Z", 
                    "2014-12-25T14:50:00.000000Z"
                ]
            }
```

I want to ask how can't I judge that if the `[]` in the 'ONE' part is null ??

I can't use `if not movietimes={}:` ,because there is `u'ONE': []` in the dict

I have to judge the first list in the dict is empty . And there are many types u'ONE',u'TWO',u'Three'

they are catch by `i.mvtype`

```
{u'ONE': []}
{u'TWO': []}
{u'Three': []}
```

Please help me ,Thank you

Comment: People or lists, don't judge them.

Comment: ...or the list might judge you back

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by "the first list in the dict"? dicts aren't ordered.

Comment: the ````[]```` part in ````{u'Three': []} ````  a guy answer my question ,I can use ````if not any(movietimes.values()) ```` but it's deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if not movietimes["Times"]["ONE"]:
    # you have empty list
```

That is presuming by first you mean the key `ONE` as dicts are not ordered

If you want to see if there is any empty  list and your dict is like below:

```
movietimes = {"Times":{"ONE":[2],"TWO":[]}}

for val in movietimes["Times"].itervalues():
   if not any(x for x in val):
        # you have empty list
```

Comment: so I have to type ["ONE"] ?? can it be catch by code . because I have many of them ["ONE"] ["Two"] ["Three"] ....

Comment: you can but it depends how your dict is structured